# netcat doesn't terminate when stdin closes

Tags: netcat

I'm trying to send a message through `netcat`. After sending the message, `netcat` must terminate.

I've tried the following:

```
cat tsmmessage.bin | nc -u localhost 4300
nc -u localhost 4300 < message.bin
```

The `-q` option states:

> -q seconds
>
> after EOF on stdin, wait the specified number of seconds and then quit. If seconds is negative, wait forever.

But

```
nc -q0 -u localhost 4300 < message.bin
```

also doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: You should probably have used the `-q 0` flag with the pipe solution (with `cat`) instead of with the redirection solution (`<` )

Answer (score 16):

Assuming that after sending EOF connection will stay idle, you can use `-w timeout` option, which works for `timeout` being equal to zero (unlike stupid `-q` option...)

```
cat tsmmessage.bin | nc -u localhost 4300 -w0
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and must be the accepted one rather than `-q`.

Comment: zero time out doesn't work on my machine (debian stretch). it says `invalid wait-time 0`

Comment: On debian stretch and debain buster, `-w0` doesn't work. I've used `-w 1` instead (with the space) and it works fine

Comment: Looking at the manpage, -q seems to be the right solution to THIS problem, though : This problem seems quite one way and doesn't suggest that the server side is replying anything on the connection. Why do you disregard the -q 0 solution ? To me it looks that that `-w …` is only useful if you want the receiver side to stop at the end of data.

Comment: Well, on Ubuntu 22.04, both -q0 and -w0 work with UDP and with TCP, so....

Answer (score 6):

Without the `-q` flag your instance of `netcat` will wait forever. There's no "end of stream" message with UDP so there is no way for `netcat` to know that both *stdin* and the network connection have finished.

For example, using TCP/IP this works as expected:

```
nc -l localhost 4300                     # Window 1
nc localhost 4300 </etc/group            # Window 2
```

But as you have determined, using UDP/IP this never ends:

```
nc -u -l localhost 4300                  # Window 1
nc -u localhost 4300 </etc/group         # Window 2
```

This is where the `-q` flag comes in. But unfortunately it doesn't accept a value of `0`. It also won't accept non-integer values. Here is the best alternative I can offer without recourse to `timeout` or some other external utility:

```
nc -u -l localhost 4300                  # Window 1
nc -q 1 -u localhost 4300 </etc/group    # Window 2
```

Even here, it's not possible to have the listening `netcat` time out gracefully. (The `-w` timeout option is ignored, and `-q` is irrelevant.) Something like this might be of use in a practical situation, so that the `netcat` is killed after 90 seconds:

```
timeout 90 nc -u -l localhost 4300       # Window 1
nc -q 1 -u localhost 4300 </etc/group    # Window 2
```

Comment: `-q 0` works for me.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka doesn't work for me though. You're definitely using UDP in your tests? What version of netcat do you have? You're probably on a more recent version.

Comment: Your first example on TCP/IP does not seem to work on Arch Linux, GNU Netcat, 0.7.1.  It hangs.  Also, the syntax for `nc -l` changed since then.

Comment: @roaima, UDP only influence the fact that the receiver side knows that the sender side has stopped. However the receiver side is not part of this problem. To stop the receiver, you need `-w`

Comment: @Camion yes, except that `-w` is (or was, back in 2017) ignored in this context

Comment: @roaima Was it ignored on the _receiver_ side ?

Comment: I would have to assume so, because I wrote, "_Even here, it's not possible to have the listening netcat time out gracefully. (The -w timeout option is ignored, and -q is irrelevant.)_"

Comment: Oh, sorry, I replied to your comment, without paying attention to the fact that you were th one who wrote the answer

Comment: No worries, @Camion, there are (at least) two different versions of `netcat` using slightly different syntax. It may well be that the version I used to create this answer has improved its functionality, or it may be that the "other" version is the dominant one these days

Answer (score 3):

## udp

```
# listen on receiver
nc -u -l localhost -p 4300

# sender
cat tsmmessage.bin | nc -u -N -q 0 localhost 4300
```

## tcp

```
# listen on receiver
nc -l localhost -p 4300

# sender
cat tsmmessage.bin | nc -N localhost 4300
```

> Edit: This solutions worked for `openbsd-netcat` for according to the comments, and does not work for `GNU Netcat` in `Archlinux`

Comment: why the downvotes ? the -N option solves this problem

Comment: out of 6 including me this solution didn't work for 2 people but has worked fine for for 4 people. 
In my case netcat is *The GNU Netcat* 0.7.1. May be it doesn't work for BSD Version.

Comment: it DOES work on the BSD version

Comment: Netcat on arch linux, (Gnu Netcat 0.7.1) does not have a -N option.

Comment: @Michaël: community/openbsd-netcat works with the options above under Arch.

Answer (score -1):

Stumbled upon this when Googling regarding pretty much the same problem. It turned out the issue was that netcat got killed by bash right after all the data got sucked in, without getting any chance to receive the response.

My solution to this was to add some delay after piping the data, like this:

```
(echo INFO; sleep 1) | nc redis.service.consul 6379
```

With a file this can look like:

```
(cat tsmmessage.bin; sleep 5) | nc -u localhost 4300
```

Comment: `netcat` still doesn't close when `sleep` finishes. I would expect the first command line to return to the prompt after 1 second, but it doesn't.

Comment: how about adding `-q 1`? i.e. `(echo INFO; sleep 1) | nc  -q 1 redis.service.consul 6379`?

Comment: With `-q` everything works, even the example in my original question. I've moved to a newer version of Ubuntu since then, maybe that causes the difference.

Comment: That's weird. Anyways, glad we both found a way around this :)

Answer (score -1):

A fairly portable option is to send SIGHUP to the client instance of `nc`. Examples:

```
kill -1 <pid of nc>
```

OR

```
pkill -1 nc
```

This also works if the data stream was already finished and you need to close the connection cleanly but nc is left running. This can happen in an environment where the closing did not work due to portability issues.